# Inject package protected (internal) classes at runtime

Tags: dependency-injection, clean-architecture

I am referring to Robert C. Martins book "Clean Architecture" on the top of page 318.

There he states:

> In the ports and adapters approach, the `OrdersService` and `Orders`
>   interfaces have inbound dependencies from other packages, so they need
>   to be made `public`. Again, the implementation classes can be made
>   `package protected` and dependency injected at runtime.

I fully understand the intention of making more components package protected rather than public.

My question is, how can the implementations be made `package protected` (`internal` in C#) if they should be dependency injected? How should the composition root access these types to register them with the IoC container?

Or is there a difference between `package protected` in Java and `internal` in C#?

Or maybe I am misinterpreting his statement?

Answer (score 1):

> How should the composition root access these types to register them with the IoC container?

One possible way to deal with this is to use a factory. Take `OrdersService` for example. In the assembly that implements this, you may have a public `IOrdersService` interface and a public `OrdersServiceFactory` that returns an instance of `IOrdersService`. The composition root then calls that factory to resolve an instance of `IOrdersService`, and it's supplied an instance of the internal class, `OrdersService`.

If at a later date, you identify a need for more than one `IOrdersService` implementation, then you just change the inner workings of the factory. The composition root doesn't have to change. That way you avoid coupling the composition root to the inner workings of other assemblies.

But things may even be further decoupled. That implementation of `IOrdersService` can be made to be the only place that creates an instance of `IOrders` when eg `myOrdersService.CreateOrder(…)` is called. In this case, there is no need to even expose some sort of factory to the composition root. It has no responsibility for creating orders so needs to know nothing about such implementations.

Comment: Just to clarify: `OrdersService` is already the interface in Uncle Bob's statement, he doesn't prefix his interfaces with `I`. 

So wouldn't that lead to a 'pattern' where we only need to create factories to be used by the composition root and only to not make the implementations public? Whereas the factories need to be public again.

Comment: @Creepin using the `I-` prefix is a common convention in C#, though not in Java.

Answer (score 0):

`internal` means it can only be accessed within the same assembly.  `package protected` in Java means they can be accessed by other classes *in the same package*.  The meaning is a little different.

Conceivably you could have external libraries using that package which could make use of that service, provided they use the same package name, so there would be no issue with implementations coming from outside the assembly.  In C#, I suppose you'd have to declare it as public, as I don't think there exists an equivalent that would work for external libraries.

Comment: So, if my composition root resides in the host application, this must have the same package name as my component to be able to access these types? I am not that into Java but I think this wouldn't solve the problem, because the main application would not have the same package name as the component where the package protected types reside. Hence, even in Java, don't I need to make these types public if I want to register them in the container from outside?

Comment: @Creepin Only the `OrdersService` and `Orders` would reside in the same package.  External libraries wanting to take advantage of this would need to necessarily create their classes in the same package to be able to "see" `Orders` in order to derive from it.  Of course you could always make it public and drop the constraint, but it is generally preferable to be more restrictive when possible.